# How do I breed a polar bear in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I breed a polar bear in Minecraft? I know the same question was already asked, but that was an old post and it only had one vague answer. The bears seem to not like raw cod or salmon and when I turned to google it said to throw the raw fish or meat on the ground in front of them. I did as google instructed and honestly- feeling a bit lied to. They did nothing. I'm wondering if it's somehow an environment thing? I have them in a grassy biome instead of an icy one. Anywho, not sure what to do. Clarifying questions welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. Polar bears can be generated with world generation or spawn as passive mobs in relevant biomes providing the passive mob cap is free (e.g. no passive mobs in spawn chunks). There is currently no method to breed them, and no way to speed up baby growth.